# Having issue collecting Json object and array with java

Tags: java, android

First of all, i am new to this so please pardon me. Have been working on a music app and I am trying to parse JSON code from a streaming link and display "artist" name and "title" of song to my app users. But i am having issues collecting the data. 
 Here is my JSON code from the streaming link:

```
{"type":"result","data":[{"title":"My Stream ","song":"Unknown - The Authorised One","track":{"artist":"Unknown Artist","title":"The Authorised One","album":"Unknown","royaltytrackid":181938.0000,"started":1498151105,"id":181938,"length":0,"playlist":{"id":3520,"title":"Rev Arome E. Adah"},"buyurl":"https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/album\/the-unknown-god\/id772022436?uo=4","imageurl":"http:\/\/is5.mzstatic.com\/image\/thumb\/Music5\/v4\/d7\/6d\/52\/d76d52df-db43-7130-0e37-62241ff50a21\/source\/100x100bb.jpg"},"bitrate":"128 Kbps","server":"Online","autodj":"Online","source":"Yes","offline":false,"summary":"<a href=\"http:\/\/cp9.serverse.com:2199\/tunein\/-stream\/svhxmwhp.pls\">Eloti Designs Stream - Unknown - The Authorised One<\/a>","listeners":0,"maxlisteners":1000,"reseller":0,"serverstate":true,"sourcestate":true,"sourceconn":1,"date":"Jun 22, 2017","time":"07:06 PM","rawmeta":"Unknown - The Authorised One ","mountpoint":"\/stream","tuneinurl":"http:\/\/209.133.216.3:7550\/stream","directtuneinurl":"","proxytuneinurl":"http:\/\/209.133.216.3\/proxy\/svhxmwhp?mp=\/stream","tuneinformat":"mp3","webplayer":"muses","servertype":"ShoutCast2","listenertotal":0,"url":"http:\/\/cp9.serverse.com:2199\/rpc"}]
```

I used this code to post "artist" name of "Unkwown Artist" to my text field but it didn't work for me.

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String songName = finalObject.getString("artist");
                return songName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`track` is a jsonobject containing `artist` and `track` is inside first `jsonobject` of 
`data` array so fetch `track` then fetch `artist` from it

```
String songName = finalObject.getJSONObject("track").getString("artist");

{
    "type":"result",
    "data":[                            // fetch JSONArray
        {                               // fetch first JSONObject
             "title":"My Stream ","song":"Unknown - The Authorised One",
             "track":{                  // fetch track JSONObject
                  "artist":"Unknown .." // fetch string
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help , stay safe out there :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the jackson parser? It's super easy to use and can easily parse the string above. All you need to do is create 3/4 POJO classes that map your structure and then apply the readValue function of the Mapper to the outer class. Following is a small example with a List and one inner class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class OutterPojo {

    public String aString;
    public List<InnerPojo> aList;

    public String getaString() {
        return aString;
    }

    public void setaString(String aString) {
        this.aString = aString;
    }

    public List<InnerPojo> getaList() {
        return aList;
    }

    public void setaList(List<InnerPojo> aList) {
        this.aList = aList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("{ #OutterPojo# ").append("aString:").append(aString).append(", ").append("aList:")
                .append(aList).append(" }").toString();
    }
}

class InnerPojo {

    public String anotherString;

    public String getanotherString() {
        return anotherString;
    }

    public void setanotherString(String anotherString) {
        this.anotherString = anotherString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("{ #InnerPojo# ").append("anotherString:").append(anotherString).append(" }")
                .toString();
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String jsonData = "{\"aString\":\"s\",\"aList\":[{\"anotherString\":\"ss\"},{\"anotherString\":\"sss\"}]}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        OutterPojo testObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, OutterPojo.class);
        System.out.println(testObject);
    }

}
```

As to dependencies all you need for this to work is jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-annotations - here's the link to maven:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Hope it helps! :)